# How to keep checkbox checked if checked by user and Notchecked if unchecked by user even after page refresh? (jquery & localStorage)

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have trying with this code to do that but have no success.
any help?

```
$(function(){
    if (jQuery("#dtype:checked").val()==1) {
        localStorage.checked = true;
        //do something
    } else {
        localStorage.checked = false;
        //do something
    }
    ('#dtype').checked = localStorage.checked;
});
```

Comment: you have a missing `$` or `jQuery` on your last line of code. Thats why its probably not working

Comment: You use wrong localStorage structure. Please check again in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: you'r right ivanov I have forgot the `$` or `jQuery` but have no success yet.

Comment: I am not sure to understand this doc properly. But may I ask you to make right structure in my code?

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `checked` property. I think you mean `$('#dtype').prop('checked', localStorage.checked);`. Also you're comparing the string from `val()` to an integer. I'd suggest using `parseInt()` to ensure the data types match.

Comment: thanks rory, I do your suggestions, but after page reload or submit checkbox set to unckecked by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `jQuery("#dtype:checked").val()==1)` always return the value, no matter checked or not. the right comparison is using one of this:

   - `$('#dtype').is(':checked')`
   - `$('#dtype').prop('checked')`
   - `$('#dtype:checked').length == 1`
2. `$('#dtype').checked` this is wrong syntax for comparison. you probably confuse about doing in pure js or jquery. see below:

   - js: document.getElementById('dtype').checked
   - jquery: $('#dtype').prop('checked')
3. localStorage only can save `String` type, you can not save it as boolean or integer, etc. `localStorage.checked = true;` will always produce `string` "true" not `boolean` "true". remember the basic `"true" !== true`
4. additional info: we can check/uncheck with jquery using this:

   - check : `$('#dtype').prop('checked', true);` or `$('#dtype').prop('checked', 1);`
   - uncheck : `$('#dtype').prop('checked', false);` or `$('#dtype').prop('checked', 0);`

Note: we can force our localStorage string to be integer using `Number()` to make this more simple

see the demo : http://jsbin.com/vigerohebi/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dtype"><br>
<button>delete localstorage</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    //initial
    console.log(localStorage.checked);
    $("#dtype").prop('checked', Number(localStorage.checked));

    //onchange
    $("#dtype").change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            localStorage.checked = 1;
            //do something
            console.log('checked');
        }else{
            localStorage.checked = 0;
            //do something
            console.log('unchecked');
        }

        console.log(localStorage.checked);
    });

    //delete localStorage
    $('button').click(function(){
        window.localStorage.removeItem('checked');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the checked item in session storage if the browser supports it and retrieve it on page load or document ready

```
  if (window.sessionStorage) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("checkedvalue", checkedvalues.selector);
  }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Retrieves the session storage for checked items
        var newcheck = sessionStorage.getItem("checkedvalue");
        $(newcheck).trigger("click");
    });
```